# magento link product to specific store view

Tags: magento

I have 6 languages defined using store views.
i have 6 simple products - one product for each language.
I did not create those products using attributes or configurable product or so, since this is the main product in my store and i would like to promote the product in each language separately.

now, I try to link a productX to default store view X (means if someone clicks to view that product, he will move to the store view with the language of the product.

example:
- store view_EN
- store view_IT

- product X_EN
- product X_IT

being in store view_EN, clicking product x_IT should redirect to store view_IT/product X_IT...

is that possible with little tweaks only?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't need 6 different products, one for each language. You can have the same product, and translate the text fields to all the languages (like name, description, short description, ...).
You can do that by changing the scope from the top-left dropdown on the product edit page, in admin.
Now here is how you can get a product url for a specific store. Let's say that the product id is `$productId`, and the store id is `$storeId`

```
$url = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId)->getProductUrl()
```

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks - 
I know i can translate a product, but i used 6 different products cause i also export my orders to openerp. Also to do combos (one language plus a dvd), it kind of needs simple products, otherwise the stock management doesn't work properly i think.

Is there no way to redirect all requests for that product to that specific store view - so nobody can end up checking out in another store view? for me the main purpose is to have the checkout in the product language - cause store view has modifications to it, so the product can be delivered from a different company/warehouse.

Comment: You can set the visibility of a product at store view level, so the customers won't be able to see Product A for language EN in other languages.

Comment: i know that - but it should be available/visible in all store views/languages - but checkout should be only in the product's language...hmm guess that's not possible eh...